# Tags and conceptual subtags

Tags: discussion, tags

If there is an existing tag "Topic1" and I want to group a collection of questions that are specifically about some subtopic of "Topic1"; what is the suggested naming for the subtopic tag?

I was thinking of something along the lines of "Topic1.SubtopicA". Ideally, "Topic1" searches would return "Topic1.SubtopicA" but "Topic1.SubtopicA" searches would only return the specific "SubtopicA" results.

Is there any way to accomplish this, or alternatively, what is the closest that I can get?

Not my actual case, but an example would be the tags 'Visual-Studio', 'Visual-Studio-2008', 'Visual-Studio-2010', 'Visual-Studio-2013'... .  Right now I have no idea where to search for a specific visual studio question, so in these cases I'm tempted to either ignore the tags altogether if I am searching or adding all of the tags if I am asking a question, but this is certainly suboptimal. Ideally, I would search for 'Visual-Studio' if I wanted everything, or 'Visual-Studio-2013' if I wanted a narrower list.  When marking a question, simply tagging it as 'Visual-Studio-2013' would also tag it as 'Visual-Studio'.

This also avoids having to run into the 5 tag maximum on any question.

Comment: There is no hierarchy support for tags.

Comment: Please cite a specific question and some specific tags: there is no tag hierarchy, but we can discuss how to appropriately tag specific questions.

Comment: There is no tag hierarchy - but it could be made! That could be pretty nice, actually.

Comment: I think tagging is a semantic web thing, thus it doesn't go well with enforced hierarchies. Because such a tag hierarchy would be also an enforced hierarchy. Instead, we have now loosely coupled tags. For example, to find html content, we should search for html and associates, and if the search AI is enough good, it will also find html5. The whole SE has this semantic direction. It is not always very good, but it plays well with google. And we have actually 3 different mechanisms to search here (google, top bar, SEDE). Knowing all the 3, we can find anything. But I think the idea is good (up).

Answer (score -4):

As the OP suggested, a (IMHO useful) practical use case is versions of a certain product/library.

He mentions Visual Studio. Certain questions relevant for - say - VS 2013 might not be relevant to VS 2018 any more.

I have a personal example with Hyperledger-Fabric
The current version is 1.4.0, some old questions mention a different version (seen an example today with 1.0.1).
As things can change quite substantially between versions, specifying a "sub-tag" might be useful to improve the signal/noise ration.

I like the idea of using `/` to separate the "main" tag from its "sub-tags".

In order to avoid proliferation of the hierarchy and simplify the code I would limit the sub-tag to 1 level.

Examples:

Visual-Studio/2018

Hyperledger-Fabric/1.4.0